# 404 not found mailgun domain on laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, mailgun

i'm actually struggling with mailgun's on laravel, I'm on laravel 6, i've set up auth and am trying to make the password reset functionnality work. So i decided to use mailgun as email server,

here is my .env file :

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:************
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=******
DB_USERNAME=******
DB_PASSWORD=******

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=postmaster@parisworld.ovh
MAIL_PASSWORD=*******
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

mail.php:

```
<?php

return [
   'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'mailgun'),
   'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
   'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
   'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'support@parisworld.ovh'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Parisworld support'),
    ],
   'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
   'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
   'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
   'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
   'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],
   'log_channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),
]
```

And my services.php:

```
<?php

   return [
    'mailgun' => [
        'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN', 'parisworld.ovh'),
        'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET', '********'),
    ],

    'postmark' => [
        'token' => env('POSTMARK_TOKEN'),
    ],

    'ses' => [
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION', 'us-east-1'),
    ],

];
```

I don't get what I'm actually missing, i configured the mailgun domain and verified the dns, everything is fine on mailgun side, I could even send myself a mail using the curl method but when I try to reset my password from my app I'm getting this error :

```
Client error: `POST https://api.mailgun.net/v3/parisworld.ovh/messages.mime` resulted in a `404 NOT FOUND` response: { "message": "Domain not found: parisworld.ovh" }
```

I hope this post is clear enought, any idea is welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

1. On Mailgun Domains page (ex. https://app.eu.mailgun.com/app/sending/domains) get your domain region;
2. Check Domain Settings -> DNS records;
3. Edit .env-file:

.env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=mg.docm****.***
MAILGUN_SECRET=d76da6b39e********

# For EU Mailgun domain region
MAILGUN_ENDPOINT=api.eu.mailgun.net

# For US Mailgun domain region
MAILGUN_ENDPOINT=api.mailgun.net
```

More information about endpoints https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-intro.html#mailgun-regions

[Mailgun: Domains page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxqkP.png)

[Mailgun: Domain Settings -> DNS records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCmgn.png)

[Mailgun: Domain Settings -> DNS records 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eh3th.png)

Answer (score 2):

Well i found the solution of this problem, I created my account in EU, by default when you refer the mailgun api url, smtp.maigun.org corresponds to the US api. So laravel was looking for the domain parisworld.ovh in the US api while it was registered in EU.
To work with mailgun's eu api you have to change in .env (in my case):

```
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
```

to

```
MAIL_HOST=smtp.eu.mailgun.org
```

I don't know why but i still had an authentification problem :

[image]

To solve this one, I just had to reset my smtp password from the mailgun interface, paste the new password in my .env and it's now working !
Hope this post will help some :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are in the EU you need to make sure you set the following in your config/services.php

```
'mailgun' => [
    'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN'),
    'endpoint' => env('MAILGUN_ENDPOINT'),
    'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET'),
],
```

and then add the following to your .env

```
MAILGUN_ENDPOINT=api.eu.mailgun.net
```

and then

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm in the Netherlands and this works for me!